# How can I perform an operation only on elements of a 2D numpy array that meet a conditional within an index without iterating in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, boolean, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to implement a solving algorithm which will use one equation if an array element is negative, and another if it is positive. Here is my code for trying to differentiate the two cases:

```
    Xn = X.copy()
    X[X[2:-2, 2:-2]>=0] = #algorithm A, calls several upstream values from Xn
    X[X[2:-2, 2:-2]<0] = #algorithm B, calls several downstream values from Xn
```

I only want to assign values to X[2:-2, 2:-2]. The shape of X is (21,21) while the X[2:-2,2:-2] is (17,17). I get this error with the above code:

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 21 but corresponding boolean dimension is 17

**How can I do this without iterating over every element?**

Answer (score 0):

Use Vectorization. That will solve all your problems.

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to Python, the two algorithms are vectorized, but how does that help me with implementing the conditionals that pick which one to use?

Comment: Vectorization help you to iterate over a NumPy array. And you have reduced the original matrix to 17*17 you have selected from 2 to 20 position thats why it is 17*17. Use if condition